# How to select into different element with Svelecte?

Tags: svelte

By default, [Svelecte](https://mskocik.github.io/svelecte/) allows selecting elements into itself. I'd like to make a selection, and append the result into some array (and render the array into some other element) or launch some other event, for example. I do not want the selected element to remain in the input.

Here is a simple example:

```
<script>
  import Svelecte from 'svelecte';
  const options = [{id: 1, value: 'Hello'}, {id: 2, value: 'World'}, {id: 3, value: 'Svelte'}];
  let selection = [];
    
  function handleChange(e) {
    if ( e.detail !== null ) {
       selection = [...selection, e.detail ];
    }
  }
</script>

<Svelecte  
    {options}
    on:change={ handleChange }
/>

<div id="selection">
    {#each selection as item }
    <div>
        {item.value}
    </div>
    {/each}
</div>
```

Somehow it works, but I have 2 problems:

- selected element remains in the Svelecte element, I'd like it cleared after making a selection
- clearing the selection adds another change event

Also, I don't feel my solution is an idiomatic way to do it. How to achieve my goal without having selected option in Svelecte element?

Here is my example in [Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/26ca4e476f50488c8d99ddcd82e2631f?version=3.59.1)

Comment: Do you mean you not only want to deselect the last option but also want to have it removed from the possible options altogether?

Comment: @Corrl Actually, no. I just like to avoid clearing the input after selection (and generating another event). I'd like to select into another element or array or launch some function, but not have the selection in the input field of Svelecte.

Comment: Like this? https://svelte.dev/repl/2837e17a61b34bb5adbf6e00b8f4eba7?version=3.59.1

Comment: @Corrl exactly!

Comment: @Corrl Can you submit as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selection can be reset via the exported `value` prop of the `Svelecte` component

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/2837e17a61b34bb5adbf6e00b8f4eba7?version=3.59.1)

```
<script>
    import Svelecte from 'svelecte';
    let options = [{id: 1, value: 'Hello'}, {id: 2, value: 'World'}, {id: 3, value: 'Svelte'}];
    let selection = [];
    let value

    function handleChange(e) {
        if ( e.detail !== null ) {
            const selected = e.detail
            selection = [...selection, selected ];
            value = null
        }
    }
</script>

<Svelecte  
                    {options}
                    bind:value
                    on:change={ handleChange }
                    />

<div id="selection">
    {#each selection as item }
    <div>
        {item.value}
    </div>
    {/each}
</div>
```